# Compose w Google Maps: mapView.getMapAsync vs mapView.awaitMap in coroutine

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In the Crane jetpack compose sample they update a MapView in an AndroidView using a remembered coroutine.

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

AndroidView({ map }) { mapView ->
    coroutineScope.launch {
        val googleMap = mapView.awaitMap()
        // ...
    }
}
```

As an exercise I removed the coroutine and instead use the old `getMapAsync`

```
AndroidView({ map }) { mapView ->
    mapView.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
        // ...
    }
}
```

This *appears* to function correctly with the same performance, it also simplifies the code a little bit (no more need to remember a coroutine and arguably less mental gymnastics going between the old and new contexts).

Is there a hidden cost to doing this?

Comment: It looks like `awaitMap` is just an extension function that wraps call to `getMapAsync`.  FWIW I'm also using `getMapAsync` in https://github.com/joreilly/GalwayBus but am also curious if there are any other implications of using `awaitMap` instead (e.g. maybe in terms of how cancellation is managed...)

Comment: That's my assumption, I'm guessing there's some rare fun that could occur if `getMapAsync` fires after the composition has been discarded...

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've figured it out.

As `awaitMap` is using a coroutine context it can be stopped/abandoned if its composition becomes invalid.

In contrast `getMapAsync` is a simple async operation with a callback.  If the composition becomes invalid while the map is still being fetched, the operation will still continue and the callback will fire.  This may lead to crashing if your callback makes assumptions about the state of your composition tree, nullable references, etc.  so should not be used.